# Debugging PHP code of a AJAX project using Eclipse PDT and Zend Debugger

Tags: ajax, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I'm not sure if I'm right or not but it seems that Eclipse PDT + Zend Debugger have problems when it comes to debugging Ajax projects. I'm working on a project in which all of the requests are passed through a single PHP file (even resource requests like downloading images). And when I want to start a debug session in Eclipse after the first request returns successfully, second forth requests return the following error message:

> A communication error occurred with the Zend Studio debugger due
> to an unfinished debug session. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
> <
>
> To reload the page click Refresh

It seems to me that since the first request is keeping the Zend Server busy, the second forth requests can not make a successful connection to it. It's in the case that I've configured the Eclipse so it won't stop at the first line of every page but still no luck.

Does this mean that in PHP + Ajax projects which requests are sent freely, it is impossible to debug? Has anyone tested this and/or the xdebug in a similar scenario?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to let my fellow developers to know that the same problem DOES NOT exist when I switched to xdebug.